# If $a-b = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a}$ , comment on $(a,b)$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If $a$ and $b$ are two **distinct** and **non-zero** real numbers such that $$ a - b = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a}$$ Determine the quadrant of $\mathrm {XY}$ plane in which the point $(a,b)$ lies.

Given, $$a-b = \frac{a-b}{ab} \implies ab=1>0$$Hence, $a$ and $b$ are of same signs and ($a,b$) lies in either $1^{st}$ or $3^{rd}$ quadrant.

Also, $$a-b = \frac{a}{b} \implies1-a= b^2> 0$$

Hence, $a<1 \implies b>1$ Or $b<0$.

However, I can't proceed further. Inserting $ab$ in place of $1$ at multiple positions is also not giving any new information. Please give a hint/solution that how I can solve it further.

Comment: Substitute $b = 1/a$ in the remaining equation, and you get an equation in $a$ alone. See what sign can $a$ have.

Comment: Shouldn't $a-b = \dfrac a b$ imply $a(b-1) = b^2$?

Comment: @AlmaArjuna Yes , but open the product and substitute $ab = 1$ .

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the hint. I found a quadratic in terms of $a$ and $b$ in which for discriminant to be greater than zero, $b<\frac{1}{4}$. However, I am trying more .

Comment: @dxiv Oh thanks, I get it.  $a^3 = a^2 - 1<0 \implies a<0$

Comment: @An_Elephant Right, and you don't even need to prove $a \lt 1$ first. It's easy to show that the cubic $a^3-a^2+1=0$ has one single real root, and that root is negative.

Comment: @dxiv Yes. I get it again. Because $f(-1)f(0)<0$ and we get it from intermediate value theorem. Thanks !

Comment: @dxiv However, proving that $~a < 1~$ allows you to bypass any consideration of a cubic equation, as per my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 Right, you can solve it either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a-b =\frac {a-b}{ab}$ implies $ab = 1$ or $b =\frac {1}{a}$`

$a-b = \frac {a}{b}$

Substituting $b = \frac {1}{a}$ from above...

$a - \frac 1a = a^2\\
a^3 - a^2+ 1 = 0$

Where is the root of this cubic?
If $a\ge 1$ then $a^3\ge a^2$ and $a^3-a^2+1>0$

If $0\le a \le 1$ then $-1 \le  a^3 - a^2 \le 0$

That is $a^3 - a^2 = a^2(a-1)$ and the absolute value of each factor must be less than 1.

Since every cubic with real coefficients has a real root, it must be that $a<0$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

Neither $~a~$ nor $~b~$ can equal $~0.~$

I agree with the OP's (i.e. original poster's) analysis that $~a~$ and $~b~$ must have the same sign, that $~a < 1,~$ and that $~ab = 1.$

Also, $~0 < a < 1 \implies 1 < b \implies (a-b) < 0.~$

This is a contradiction because

$$a - b = \frac{a}{b} > 0.$$

Therefore, you must have that $~a < 0 \implies b < 0.$

Comment: Good observation !